# Xcode Storyboard file displaying source control diff interface

Tags: swift, storyboard, swift4

When I click on my Storyboard file, I can't see the UI I made.

It's showing some code instead of my UI.

How can I see my Storyboard user interface?

[image: this issue]

Answer (score 1):

Press this button to see your UI back. This is not an issue it is a feature of Xcode to see your code behind the storyboard's UI

[image]